# Security notification bar

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, web-reference

I need to add a web reference in Visual Studio 2012 (because service reference generates a blank reference CS and I have given up after hours of googling).

When I go to add the web reference (<kbd>add service reference</kbd> → <kbd>advanced</kbd> → <kbd>add web reference</kbd>) and enter the `WSDL URL` I get the IE Notification Bar in the dialog with the message:

`To help protect your security, your web browser has blocked this site from downloading files to your computer`. The option to "Download file" does not work.

I've changed IE security settings to minimum and added the domain to the list of trusted sites but did not have any effect. I also uninstalled `IE10` completely and still get the notification bar. I am using Windows 8.

Anyone shed any light on this or had any success adding a web reference in VS 2012?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the wsdl file to disk and adding the webreference from there? Have you tried svcutil.exe or wsdl.exe to generate the wsdl from the commandline, completely outside of Visual Studio?

Comment: Is it a public WSDL so we can give it a try?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I downloaded the file and added the reference that way. Didn't realize that would work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you can download the WSDL with your browser, download it and save it to a file. You can then reference it from Visual Studio by pointing it to that file. Or you can use `svcutil.exe` or `wsdl.exe` to generate a proxy from the commandline.